# how to create a visual web part in the following format

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, visual-web-part

[image]

I am a newbie to Visual Studio, it would be great if someone could provide me with an idea how to create the webpart in the following format

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASP.NET Repeater Control](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp) in your Visual Web Part.. and get list data using [SPList.GetItems(SPQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitems.aspx)

You can see an [example of SPQuery here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx)..

You can either bind SPListItemCollection to Repeater or you can use [SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) and bind Repeater to DataTable..